# Session variable being written over by the next variable in the session array

Tags: php, session

Ok I have a navbar link which upon click goes to **language.php**.

My code for my navbar which is located in a seperate view folder `views/header/header2.php`.

```
<?php 
    $_SESSION['from'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="position:top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="sr-only"><img src="images/dp.png"></button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
            <img src="views/images/cp.png" title="###.###" alt="logo" width="90px" height="48px" style="padding-top:2px"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" ></span> <?php echo HEADER_PAGE; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="search.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> <?php echo HEADER_SEARCH; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="post.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <?php echo HEADER_POST; ?></a></li>   
            <li><a href="community.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> <?php echo HEADER_COMMUNITY; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="edit.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <?php echo HEADER_EDIT; ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="language.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></span> <?php echo HEADER_LANGUAGE; ?></a></li>
            <li style="background-color:white"><a style="color:black" href="index.php?logout"><?php echo WORDING_LOGOUT; ?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Code for my language.php which is located in the main directory.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
        $from = $_SESSION['from'];
        $langSession = $_SESSION['lang'];
        if($langSession == "th"){
            $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
            //header('Location:http://www.###.###'.$from);
            echo $from;
        } elseif ($langSession == "en"){
            $_SESSION['lang'] = "th";
            //header('Location:http://www.###.###'.$from);
            echo $from;
        }
        if(!(isset($langSession))){
            $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
            //header('Location:http://www.###.###'.$from);
            echo $from;
        }
    } 
?>
```

The problem is in my language.php file:
 I commented out the header(Locations:"www.###.###".$from) and used `echo $from ($from = $_SESSION['from']` (in order to find what the variable is reading) once I'm on `location.php` before the `redirect. $from` reads as `3`. When I checked prior to the location.php execution, `index.php` showed $from to be `/index.php` which is correct.

Issue: Once I click on the link for `language.php`, `$from` changes to the integer **3**.

With using the `header()` it sends me to `http://www.###.###3` (The number 3 is coming from another session variable user `ID $_SESSION['id']`, which is from the next index in the array of `$_SESSION` variables).

I tried logging in with a different user and it changed the number according to that user's ID so that's confirmed that the following `$_SESSION` variable is overwriting the prior one. I just have no clue why it is doing that and changing the `$_SESSION['from']` variable.

Now it's working with ALL of the other pages except `index.php`.

My code for `index.php`

```
<?php
ob_start();
// check for minimum PHP version
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<')) {
    exit('Sorry, this script does not run on a PHP version smaller than 5.3.7 !');
} else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')) {
    // if you are using PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 you have to include the password_api_compatibility_library.php
    // (this library adds the PHP 5.5 password hashing functions to older versions of PHP)
    require_once('libraries/password_compatibility_library.php');
}
// include the config
require_once('config/db/config.php');

// include translation
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
} elseif(!(isset($_SESSION['lang']))) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
$_SESSION['from'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

require_once("translations/$lang.php");

// include the PHPMailer library
require_once('libraries/PHPMailer.php');

// load the login class
require_once('classes/Login.php');

// create a login object. when this object is created, it will do all login/logout stuff automatically
// so this single line handles the entire login process.
$login = new Login();

// ... ask if we are logged in here:
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true){
    // the user is logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
    // for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are logged in" view.
    include("views/logged_in.php");
} else {
    // the user is not logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
    // for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are not logged in" view.
    include("views/landing.php");
}
```

PS. I've turned off registered globals via **.htaccess**

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Try printing $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in header2.php so you could see it on every page. Is it correct in all cases, on all pages?

Comment: Yes, on all pages it is showing the correct variable on all pages. Only when I click the <a href="language.php"> link does it change the variable to the number 3. Which is the value for $_SESSION['user_id'];

Comment: you say if you add to header2.php the following: `echo "URI: >".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']."<";` it displays there precisely `URI: >3<` ?

Comment: No that will display URI: >index.php?<, something is happening after the link (language.php) is clicked. In all the pages the URI displays the corrent value. when language.php is loaded after the link click, the value for $_SESSION['from'] changes to value for the following $_SESSION variable in the array.

Comment: It's unclear how everything's assembled together. When language.php starts? Is it included in index.php? What about header2.php ? I think they are, but it isn't clear or seen anywhere

Comment: header2.php is included in all of the files that the user is "logged_in" on. language.php starts when you click on <li><a href="language.php"></a></li> which is located in the header2.php file. *above* / It is not included in anything. Language.php is just a file that takes the $_SESSION['lang'] variable and assigns an include file depending on the assigned variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69118/discussion-between-dustin-lawrence-and-oleg-dubas).

Comment: Anyone else having understanding this? If so I'll try to make it better understood.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by renaming $_SESSION['from'] to $_SESSION['link'] and it is working correctly again. I'm assuming $_SESSION['from'] is trying to be set by something else. I've browsed through all of my code that is involved in these actions and there is nothing. Anyone have an explanation for why it changed the value of $_SESSION['from'] to the value of $_SESSION['user_id']?

As in $from = $_SESSION['from'] then it is assigned the value of $_SESSION['user_id']...